# HTML padding with 100% width and height?

Tags: html, css

I have some screen area (a parent div) that I want my `<div>` to completely fill up, but I also want to have a 5% gap around the its content. How could this best be implemented?

If I apply the rules: `width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 5%;` they produce the desired effect (at least for `<div>` itself) but its bounds now exceed its parent element's bounds by `2 * padding`px.

How can I ensure this `<div>`'s bounds take up 100% of its parent's, and still retains a 5% padding, without overflowing?

Note: I'm sure that I could find some hack ("just set width and height to 90%, since padding is 5%..), what I'm interested in is the most elegant, future proof, and intelligent solution.  It seems that certain problems around positioning and sizing of individual divs almost totally go away when you are able to use more modern CSS technologies like Grid and Flex-box, so I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Can you post some code and / or screenshot to help us understand the exact problem and provide an accurate (possible) solution.

Comment: i think my explanation thoroughly explains the rather simple condition.  anyway, the answer i got for using border-box exactly solves this problem of padding and width/height.

Comment: make a parent <div width 100%> and make a child <div margin 5%> <div id="parent" style="width:100%;"><div id="child" style="margin:5%;">your content here</div></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if my thought is right you need to use `box-sizing:border-box` , Specify that  elements should have padding and border included in the element's total width and height:

like

```
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

please check this snippet

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.demo {
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  float:left;
  background:#000;
  padding:5%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Comment: i actually had that style set on my body tag. i wonder if it did not cascade down.  you also have me worried with the prefixing as I'm not doing any prefixing.  I'm on chrome..

Comment: did you use with `*` , this will keep all your content with `border-box` property eg: (div,span,anchor) etc

Comment: i had the rule applied to `html, body`